# Shellsort recursivo en C con arreglo dinamico , error al compilar

Tags: c, shell, ordenamiento

e intentado aplicar el metodo de shellsort recursivo para una tarea pero parece que la logica me anda fallando y queria ver si alguien me podia ayudar,
para saber como lo quiero implementar , es en base a este video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9GAtGHVRYh0), me he fijado que dependiendo del video la forma de ejecucion que explican es distinta, algunas separece mas al burbuja y otro itera hacia atras, intente hacer el segundo aunque sin exito, en fin este es mi codigo y lo tengo con comentarios para ayudar a ver de manera mas sensilla el error:
(En fin para dar un poco de contexto al desorden, la idea es primero definir el numero de espacios el que me saltare (n total /2), despues de eso, comparar si el que esta a la izquierda es mayor que el que esta a la derecha, si es asi, los cambia, y ve si los numeros que estan atras (separado por el mismo desplazamiento) pasa lo mismo, si es asi, tambien cambia los que estan por atras, hasta que se tope con el cero, o hasta que el que esta a la izquierda deje de ser mayor) , luego vuelve a dividir el desplzamienrto en 2 y asi... , resultado = catastrofe)

````
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<time.h>

//Paso 3 ,entrego vector, el auxiliar que cree en funcion chelsor, y los espacios a avanzar
//realiza esto, solo si la condicion anterior se cumple, si no hay cambio, no revisa hacia atras
void cambiodecendente (int long *listamillones, long int auxdeposicion, long int avance ){
    long int segundoaux;
  // verifica si me paso de la posicion cero, verifica, si el dato en que tengo atras
  //es mayor al que esta adelante, intercambia
    if (auxdeposicion-avance>=0 && listamillones[auxdeposicion-avance] > listamillones[auxdeposicion]){
      //el mayor lo guardo
      segundoaux = listamillones [auxdeposicion-avance]; 
      //donde estaba el mayor , ahora dejo el menor
        listamillones[auxdeposicion-avance]=listamillones[auxdeposicion];
      //en la posicion mas a la derecha, le asigno el mayor
        listamillones[auxdeposicion]=segundoaux;
      //si encontre menores antes de la posicion del paso 2, sigo operando hacia atras
      //cuando, el indice sea menor a 0. o que el de la izquierda sea menor, deja de llamarse
    cambiodecendente (listamillones , auxdeposicion-avance , avance);
    }
}
//Paso 2, intercambio , entrego lista, la posicion de los que quiero cambiar y el avance
void cambioascendente(int long *listamillones ,long int posicion , long int avance){
    long int aux , auxdeposicion;
    aux=listamillones[posicion];
    //guardo el menor en la posicion
    listamillones[posicion] = listamillones [posicion+avance];
    listamillones[posicion + avance] = aux;
  //para no modificar posicion, cree una auxiliar de la misma
  auxdeposicion = posicion;
    //hacia el paso 3, si hice un cambio, vere si puedo cambiar los anteriores
      cambiodecendente (listamillones , auxdeposicion , avance);
}

// paso 1 definir la funcion shelsort , parametro arreglo, la posicion inicio , el tamaño a partir, y total
void chelsor (int long *listamillones, long int posicion, long int tamaño , long int tamañototal){
  //el avance es la cantidad de espacios que se movera por cada iteracion
    long int avance = (tamaño+1)/2 , aux ;
  //hacer por lo menos una vez
    do {
  //si el contenido la posicion actual es mayor a la posicion con  el avance , intercambia
    if (listamillones [posicion]>listamillones [posicion+avance] ){
      //aca se genera el cambio, le entrego el arreglo la posiciony lo que quiero avanzar, hacia elpaso 2
      cambioascendente (listamillones ,posicion , avance );
    
      }
    //paso 4 , cuando deja de ver hacia atras (paso 3), la posicion avanza  
    
      posicion++;
    } while (posicion+avance < tamañototal);//repito hasta que me pase del limite
  if(avance >0)
chelsor (listamillones , posicion , tamaño/2 , tamañototal);
  //sigo solo si el avance entre posiciones es de 2, ya que la ultima ejecucion es cuando vale uno
  }


int main() {
srand48(time(NULL));
long int TAMA=8, i;
long int*listamillones;
listamillones=malloc(TAMA * sizeof(long int));
for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++ ){
  listamillones[i] = lrand48()%2000 ;}

  chelsor (listamillones , 0 , TAMA , TAMA);

for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++ ){
printf ("%ld   " , listamillones [i]);}

    return 0;
} ```
````

Answer (score 0):

Hice unas pequeñas modificaciones, el algoritmo es completamente funcional y absurdamente rapido, ordeno 10 millones de datos en 2 segundos. solo tuve que reiniciar el indice a 0 (se mantenia al maximo asi que el resultado correspondia solo a la primera iteracion)
el nuevo codigo del shellsort recursivo es este:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
void chelsor (long int *listamillones, long int posicion, long int tamaño , long int tamañototal){
  long int  avance, auxiliar;
  if (tamaño=1){
    tamaño=tamaño*2;}
  avance= tamaño/2 ;
  int ordenado=0;
  
  while ((posicion+ avance) < tamañototal){
    if (listamillones [posicion]>listamillones[posicion + avance]){
      auxiliar = listamillones[posicion];
      listamillones [posicion] = listamillones[posicion + avance];
      listamillones [posicion + avance]=auxiliar;
      ordenado++; }
    posicion++;
  }
  posicion = 0;
  if (ordenado>0){
    chelsor (listamillones, posicion, tamaño/2 , tamañototal);
  }
  }
int main(  ) {
  printf("Hello World\n");
  //defino tamano del vector
long int TAMA=10000, i;
//creo vector dinamico para poner muchisimos digitos
long int *listamillones;
//reservo memoria
listamillones =  malloc( TAMA *sizeof (long int));
srand48(time(NULL));
//lleno el vector con numeros aleatorios
for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++){
    listamillones[i] = lrand48()%2000000;}
//le doy a la funcion el vector con datos y tamaño
  chelsor (listamillones , 0 , TAMA , TAMA);
    for (i=0 ; i<TAMA ; i++)
  printf ("%ld  ", listamillones[i]);
  return 0;}
```

Comment: ¿Pudiste solucionar el problema? Si es así, cuando en unos días te deje aceptarla como respuesta, hazlo.

Comment: @Mateo si, aunque no sé como dejarla como respuesta , la verdad es que soy nuevo jaja

Comment: Dale clic al tilde ✓ que está debajo del puntaje de la respuesta.